# Pandas Series.apply() not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, pandas-apply

I am trying to apply a function to check if the strings stored in a series are numbers and if so turn them into None, if not do nothing. The Series is as follows:

```
0 'EUR'
1 '327'
2 'None'
3 'USD'
```

The functions to check if entries are a number represented as a string:

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except (TypeError,ValueError):
        pass

    try:
        import unicodedata
        unicodedata.numeric(s)
        return True
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass

    return False


def num_to_none(target):
    if is_number(target):
        target = None
```

I call the function like so:

```
result = mySeries.apply(num_to_none)
```

But I get the following result for res:

```
    0 'None'
    1 'None'
    2 'None'
    3 'None'
```

The desired result is:

```
0 'EUR'
1 'None'
2 'None'
3 'USD'
```

I am currently just playing around with this in a test environment with a small dataframe (10000 rows, 70 columns) but I hope to apply it to a much larger dataframe if I can get it working so efficiency advice is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` the result from your `num_to_none` function

```
def num_to_none(target):
    if is_number(target):
        target = None
    return target
```

The reason it appears your function is not behaving correctly is because if there is no `return` statement, the default behaviour is `return None`

#### Example

```
def my_function():
    print "hello world"
```

is equivalent to

```
def my_function():
    print "hello world"
    return None
```

Comment: I thought that the function returning None automatically when the if statement is false would mean that target would not be changed...

Comment: You are correct: if the `if` statement is false, the variable `target` is never changed. However `.apply(num_to_none)` is using the result (the `return` value) from your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isnumeric` and `where` as an alternative for you function i.e

```
s.where(~s.str.isnumeric(),'None')
# or 
s.mask(s.str.isnumeric(),'None')

0     EUR
1    None
2    None
3     USD
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(mySeries.str.strip("'"), errors='coerce').notnull()
result = mySeries.mask(m, "'None'")
print (result)
0     'EUR'
1    'None'
2    'None'
3     'USD'
Name: a, dtype: object
```